# AngularJS or CSS - Issue with table with many rows and first column fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a table with first column fixed and horizontal scrolling for the other columns.
We obtained this with a specific CSS class for the cells of the first column, as shown below:

```
tr > th.fixed, td.fixed {
  position:absolute;
  width: 25em;
  left: 3em;
  top:auto;
}
```

The HTML code is the following:

```
<div class="fm-list-container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      ...
    </table> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

We set *overflow-x: auto* for the internal div ("table-responsive" CSS class) and *overflow-y: visible* for the external div ("fm-list-container" CSS class).
If we have many rows the horizontal scrollbar is shown on bottom of the table, so it is not visible. Is there a way to have horizontal scrollbar always visible (with first column frozen)?
We have tried to set *max-height* of the internal div but this property is not applied for the first column. Thus, the first column and the other ones have different vertical scrolling.
Is there a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap which it looks like use the angular js version
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Then using max-height should work.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Would you use some bootstrap component instead of html table?

Comment: So instead of including bootstrap.min.js from the bootstrap website. you need to download and include the one that works with angular js from the website, otherwise, you will find certain things just don't work as you would expect.
You also need to include it in your module something like
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);